# How can i query build in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

If i want to make something like this in sql:
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE id = 1111
AND (column1 is null OR column2 = 'sample')

I try with "->where(..)->orWhereNull(...)", but it is not my point (like without () is query)

Comment: Read up on Logical Grouping in Laravel - https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#logical-grouping

Comment: So what's the problem here? I can't understand.

Comment: IF i try with "->where(..)->orWhereNull(...)" i get all the expressions in which id is equal to 222,333,444...

Answer (score 0):

Use  Logical Grouping in Laravel, thanks aynber:

```
->where('id', 1111)
->where(function ($q) {
            $q->where('column2', 'sample')
            ->orWhereNull('column1');
        })
```